# Is this a good title?

Tags: android, crash, android-7.0-nougat

My app works flawlessly on previous builds of Android, tested from 4.0 to 6.0.1 on actual devices. No problem in Studio-emulated Nougat 7.0 and 7.1. However, when I have my friend test the APK on his device running 7.0, I get "{AppName} keeps crashing" within a few seconds.

I do not have access to the device (he lives far away) and I cannot find any relevant information for this specific error online. What might be the cause?

Comment: "I cannot find any relevant information for this specific error online" -- there is no "specific error" in your screenshot. Integrate a crash logging solution into your app (e.g., [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) and your chosen backend), so that you have a stack trace and other information to work with.

Comment: I was wrong to call it an "error," but there is still little info on that specific notice. I will take a look at ACRA. Thanks!

Comment: That dialog is what you get when you crash. It's not directly informative, as the details (e.g., stack trace) will be unintelligible to most users. But, that's where crash logging and reporting comes into play, so you can get the stack trace and relevant details.

Comment: What I found strange about it was the wording. In my (minuscule) experience, the notice is usually "Unfortunately, app has stopped" but this is a different dialog, perhaps Nougat-specific? But you're right again, I was ignorant to hope that would be enough! xD

Comment: I think that the revised phrasing kicks in after a few crashes, and I think that you're right and it's new to 7.0. I'm not aware of any functional difference, though.

Comment: After much trial and error, I was able to use ACRA and discover that it was a non-Nougat-related RuntimeException. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey @RogerG  I am having same issue in Nougat devices. What is exactly the reason behind this?

Comment: @RogerG        I am also having this issue, can you please post some more details on what was causing it and what you had to do?  I am going to look into ACRA now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the badge content provider? Samsung Nougat 7.0 may have caused the crash:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.sec.android.provider.badge.BadgeProvider uri content://com.sec.badge/apps from pid=22957, uid=10208 requires com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE, or grantUriPermission()